# How to find max or min of a column in a data.table up to a given time in a day

Tags: r, data.table

I've got some financial time series in one-minute intervals ("bars").  Because I'll be dealing with some large series, I'm learning to use `data.table`, and I'm not quite used to thinking in the `data.table` way yet.
In the data I've imported into a `data.table` (let's call it `DT` here for simplicity), among other things not relevant to this question, I've got a column called `Date` in `YYYYMMDD` format, a column called `Time` in `HH:MM` format, and a column called `Price` (let's say it's the final price for that minute) that's an integer.  I'm simplifying a little, but if anyone can help me with the question I'm asking here, I can adapt it to the details of my data.  Here's an example:

```
Date     Time  Price
20151028 09:00 47675
20151028 09:01 47650
20151028 09:02 47670
20151028 09:03 47685
20151028 09:04 47690
...
```

What I'd like to do is calculate, for each minute, the maximum and minimum values of `Price` in the day up to that minute.  Let's go ahead and add the things I want to calculate as additional columns, which I'll call `DayMax`  and `DayMin` here.  The result would then look like this:

```
Date     Time  Price DayMax DayMin
20151028 09:00 47675 47675  47675
20151028 09:01 47650 47675  47650
20151028 09:02 47670 47675  47650
20151028 09:03 47685 47685  47650
20151028 09:04 47690 47690  47650
...
```

I'm pretty sure my `by` (which I understand as being like a `GROUP BY` in SQL) should be `Date`, and I think what I'm having trouble understanding is how to set up my `i` (like a `WHERE` in SQL), basically because I'm not sure how to use the same column two different ways in the syntax.  For each row, I want to calculate the maximum where (and by "where," I think I mean `WHERE`) `Time` is less than or equal to the value of `Time` in that specific row, and where I'm `GROUP`(ing)`BY` Date, so it's up to that line's time in the specific day.  How can I do this in a quick and memory-efficient way using `data.table`?
By the way, speaking of "quick and memory-efficient," I'm assuming I should use the `:=` operator to create the new columns.  Please correct me if I'm wrong about that.

Comment: Try `cummin` and `cummax`. If you want more specific help, you'll probably want to follow the site's guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250

Comment: @Frank, you are right, of course. I will make sure to provide R code to produce example data in future questions. Should I edit the question to add such code?

Comment: Nope, that's okay; looks like it was good enough for Uwe to answer already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As suggested by Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42882958/how-to-find-max-or-min-of-a-column-in-a-data-table-up-to-a-given-time-in-a-day#comment72869189_42882958), `cummin()` and `cummax()` will do that for you. (In SQL this is called *window function* or *analytic function* in ORACLE, I believe).

```
DT[order(Date, Time), `:=`(DayMax = cummax(Price), DayMin = cummin(Price)), by = Date]
DT
#       Date  Time Price DayMax DayMin
#1: 20151028 09:00 47675  47675  47675
#2: 20151028 09:01 47650  47675  47650
#3: 20151028 09:02 47670  47675  47650
#4: 20151028 09:03 47685  47685  47650
#5: 20151028 09:04 47690  47690  47650
```

Just to make sure the data are in the proper order, `DT` is ordered by `Date`and `Time`. This can be skipped if this is ensured by previous steps. The two new columns are computed within one expression, separately for each `Date` as requested.

Using chaining, this could be rewritten as

```
res <- DT[order(Date, Time)][, DayMax := cummax(Price), by = Date][, DayMin := cummin(Price), by = Date][]
```

but this has the disadvantage that a copy of `DT` is created instead of `DT` being modified *by reference* plus requiring an additional grouping operation (Thanks to [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank) for pointing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42882958/how-to-find-max-or-min-of-a-column-in-a-data-table-up-to-a-given-time-in-a-day/42884204?noredirect=1#comment72877129_42884204) out).

### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread ("Date     Time  Price
         20151028 09:00 47675
         20151028 09:01 47650
         20151028 09:02 47670
         20151028 09:03 47685
         20151028 09:04 47690")
```

Comment: Uwe Block, I had written a comment this morning thanking you for this, but I guess I forgot to click on "Add Comment."  Thanks so much for this answer!  As @Frank correctly pointed out in a comment on the question, I had failed to provide R code to produce the example data, but even so, you wrote an answer that was thorough and very useful to me.  You even papered over my mistake by providing simple code to reproduce the example data!

Comment: @Phys-math-stat No worries, I appreciate your carefully crafted Q which demonstrate your efforts to understand `data.table` syntax.

Comment: Each programming language ends up requiring me to think in a different way.  I have my own way of thinking about how to do things in R, but now that I've found `data.table`, everything is changing.  I'm starting to get some of the syntax and the way of thinking, but it's not natural yet. I am sure it's worth learning, and I'm enjoying the learning process. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Phys-math-stat Perhaps you already have discovered https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started. I found the vignettes including the FAQ very helpful in understanding the potential of `data.table`. Section 2.16 of the FAQ explaining how `data.table` syntax relates to `SQL helped me a lot.

Comment: I had been seeing those things on rawgit, which is where the links from the github page point.  The date on rawgit appears to be off by three months.  For anyone else reading this who's trying to learn `data.table`, I recommend the vignettes linked by Uwe Block.  They're really useful.  Thanks again, UB!